# How to extract EBP and ESP from Core Dump?

Tags: linux, gdb, cpu-registers, coredump

I'm trying to analyze a core dump from a program without debug infos (Linux). The analyzing should be done automatically in C, so **no** GDB.

As I've seen in GDB, it is possible to get the top of stack pointer and the stack base pointer (ESP and EBP) via the command `info registers`. And when I go up or down the stack (command `up` and `down`) I see the updated version of the registers for the current frame.

My question is, where do I find this information in the core dump? I know there is a NOTE section in the core dump that contains NT_PRSTATUS, NT_PRPSINFO and NT_AUXV. But sadly, I can't find any information about that notes. How does GDB build of the frames, where does it take the informations from?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First you need to read the ELF specification and then read the function elf_core_dump() in the linux/fs/binfmt_elf.c to get to know how the coredump file is organised. But anyway, you can check the following program.

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <elf.h>
 #include <sys/types.h>
 #include <unistd.h>
 #include <fcntl.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <sys/procfs.h>

 int main (int argc, char **arg)
 {
Elf32_Ehdr *elfh;
Elf32_Shdr *elfsh;
Elf32_Phdr *elfphdr;
char *p = NULL;
char buf[1000], sbuf[1000];
int ret, fd, i = 0, size;

if (argc < 2) {
    printf("\nUsage: corenotes <core>\n");
    return 0;
}

fd = open(arg[1], O_RDONLY);
if (fd < 0) {
    perror("open");
    return 0;
}

/* Read ELF header*/
ret = read(fd, buf, sizeof(*elfh));
if (!ret) {
    perror("Error Reading the ELF Header");
    goto cl;
}
elfh = (Elf32_Ehdr *) buf;
/* Is it ELF*/
if ((elfh->e_ident[0] != 0x7f) || (elfh->e_ident[1] != 'E') ||
    (elfh->e_ident[2] != 'L') || (elfh->e_ident[3] != 'F')) {
    printf("\nUnrecongised File Format");
    goto cl;
}

/*
 * read program headers and print
 */
size = elfh->e_phnum * elfh->e_phentsize;
p =  malloc(size);

lseek(fd, elfh->e_phoff, SEEK_SET); 
ret = read(fd, p, size);
if (ret != size) {
    printf("\nCannot read Program Header");
    goto cl;
}
elfphdr = (Elf32_Phdr *)p;
for (i = 0; i < elfh->e_phnum; i++) {
    if (elfphdr->p_type == PT_NOTE) {
        unsigned char *pdata;
        struct note {
            unsigned int namesz;
            unsigned int descsz;
            unsigned int type;
        };
        struct note *not;
        int pad;

        pdata = malloc(elfphdr->p_filesz);
        lseek(fd, elfphdr->p_offset, SEEK_SET);
        ret = read(fd, pdata, elfphdr->p_filesz);
        not = (struct note *) pdata;
        printf("\n%s", pdata + sizeof (*not));
        pad  = 4 - (not->namesz % 4); 
        if (not->type == NT_PRSTATUS) {
            struct elf_prstatus *prs;

            prs = (struct elf_prstatus *)(pdata + sizeof(*not) + not->namesz + pad);
            printf("\nProgram Received %d", prs->pr_cursig);
            printf("\nPending Signals %08x", prs->pr_sigpend);
            printf("\nHold Signals %08x", prs->pr_sighold);
            printf("\nPID of the process %d", prs->pr_pid);
            printf("\nPPID of the process %d", prs->pr_ppid);
            printf("\nEBX: %08x", prs->pr_reg[0]);
            printf("\nECX: %08x", prs->pr_reg[1]);
            printf("\nEDX: %08x", prs->pr_reg[2]);
            printf("\nESI: %08x", prs->pr_reg[3]);
            printf("\nEDI: %08x", prs->pr_reg[4]);
            printf("\nEBP: %08x", prs->pr_reg[5]);
            printf("\nEAX: %08x", prs->pr_reg[6]);
            printf("\nXDS: %08x", prs->pr_reg[7]);
            printf("\nXES: %08x", prs->pr_reg[8]);
            printf("\nXFS: %08x", prs->pr_reg[9]);
            printf("\nXGS: %08x", prs->pr_reg[10]);
            printf("\nORG_EAX: %08x", prs->pr_reg[11]);
            printf("\nEIP: %08x", prs->pr_reg[12]);
            printf("\nECS: %08x", prs->pr_reg[13]);
            printf("\nEFLAGS: %08x", prs->pr_reg[14]);
            printf("\nESP: %08x", prs->pr_reg[15]);
            printf("\nXSS: %08x", prs->pr_reg[16]);
            pdata = pdata + sizeof(*not) + not->namesz + pad + sizeof(struct elf_prstatus);
        }
         not = (struct note *)pdata;
         if (not->type == NT_PRPSINFO) {
            struct elf_prpsinfo *prs;
            printf("\n\nNT_PRPSINF\n");
            pad  = 4 - (not->namesz % 4);
            prs = (struct elf_prpsinfo *)(pdata + sizeof(*not) + not->namesz + pad);
            printf("\nName of the Exe %s", prs->pr_fname);
        }
    //  free(pdata);
    }
    elfphdr++;
}
  free(p);      
  printf("\n\n");
  cl:   
  close(fd);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: please reproduce the relevant portion of your answer here so that SO users don't have to count on your source code being served at the link you provide.

Comment: Brain, you want me to paste the code here?. It's a big code that's why I didn't paste it here. If that is not an issue I will paste the code here.

Comment: Yes, post it here.  Don't worry, Joel will pick up the storage bill.

Comment: But I have a question. You calculate the padding with `4 - (name_size % 4)`. This means that you add 4 bytes if the name_size is a multiple of 4. Is this right?
Or should it be `(4 - (name_size % 4)) % 4`?

Comment: As per the documentation, name size should be in multiples of 4. If it is not, remaining 1 or 2 or 3 bytes will be padded. But not->namesz contains the actual size of the name, so I am skipping the remaining bytes(1 or 2 or 3) to get to the next field.

Comment: Yes but if the name is actually a multiple of 4 bytes, you add another 4 bytes and so you would skip the first four bytes of the description field, wouldn't you?

Answer (score 0):

elf is a complex fomat, use libelf to extract PT_NOTE. 
Skip others, NT_PRSTATUS have what you need.

If you can call other program, you will have better luck with elfdump.

you can find NT_PRSTATUS format here: 
http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/elfcore.h#L42
http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/include/asm/elf.h#L116